# Glamor Graphic Errors troubleshooting libcamera on headless raspberry pi zero w

Tags: camera, pi-zero-w, gpu, libcamera

I've been trying to troubleshoot libcamera by enabling glamor graphics acceleration on my raspberry pi zero w v1.1.  When trying to run I get the following followed by the process just hanging forever.

```
pi@luna:~ $ libcamera-hello
Preview window unavailable
[6:12:41.086038212] [1294]  INFO Camera camera_manager.cpp:293 libcamera v0.0.0+3424-e68e0f1e
[6:12:41.171248040] [1295] ERROR CameraSensor camera_sensor.cpp:551 'ov5647 10-0036': Camera sensor does not support test pattern modes.
[6:12:41.293652793] [1295]  INFO RPI raspberrypi.cpp:1317 Registered camera /base/soc/i2c0mux/i2c@1/ov5647@36 to Unicam device /dev/media3 and ISP device /dev/media0
[6:12:41.298469783] [1294]  INFO Camera camera.cpp:1028 configuring streams: (0) 1296x972-YUV420
[6:12:41.301267777] [1295]  INFO RPI raspberrypi.cpp:747 Sensor: /base/soc/i2c0mux/i2c@1/ov5647@36 - Selected sensor format: 1296x972-SGBRG10_1X10 - Selected unicam format: 1296x972-pGAA
[6:12:41.384747609] [1299]  INFO IPARPI raspberrypi.cpp:631 Request ctrl: Saturation = 1.000000
[6:12:41.386718605] [1299]  INFO IPARPI raspberrypi.cpp:631 Request ctrl: Contrast = 1.000000
[6:12:41.388477601] [1299]  INFO IPARPI raspberrypi.cpp:631 Request ctrl: Brightness = 0.000000
[6:12:41.391250596] [1299]  INFO IPARPI raspberrypi.cpp:631 Request ctrl: AwbMode = 0
[6:12:41.394287590] [1299]  INFO IPARPI raspberrypi.cpp:631 Request ctrl: Sharpness = 1.000000
[6:12:41.396645585] [1299]  INFO IPARPI raspberrypi.cpp:631 Request ctrl: ExposureValue = 0.000000
[6:12:41.399210580] [1299]  INFO IPARPI raspberrypi.cpp:631 Request ctrl: AeExposureMode = 0
[6:12:41.400820576] [1299]  INFO IPARPI raspberrypi.cpp:631 Request ctrl: FrameDurationLimits = [ 33333, 33333 ]
[6:12:41.401804574] [1299]  INFO IPARPI raspberrypi.cpp:631 Request ctrl: AeMeteringMode = 0
[6:12:41.403554571] [1299]  INFO IPARPI raspberrypi.cpp:631 Request ctrl: NoiseReductionMode = 3
```

I have two cameras attached through an [adapter](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07VD9XLYH).  They have [a repo](https://github.com/ArduCAM/RaspberryPi) that I'm using.  The most direct path for what I want is to run [their shell script](https://github.com/ArduCAM/RaspberryPi/blob/master/Multi_Camera_Adapter/Multi_Adapter_Board_2Channel_uc444/shell/pi_cam_uc444.sh), that ultimately is making use of libcamera.  When I run their script, I get more or less the same as above.  In communication with support, I've been asked to activate my glamor graphics acceleration.  When I try to do this, I get the following:

```
pi@luna:~ $ sudo raspi-config
Failed to disable unit: Unit file glamor-test.service does not exist.
Failed to stop glamor-test.service: Unit glamor-test.service not loaded.
```

Do I have to install glamor drivers from somewhere?  My pi is headless, but it should still have the ability to make use of graphical acceleration, right?  If I could get some guidance on where I should start looking to fix my libcamera issue and/or this glamor issue, I'd appreciate it.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

in terminal you can open change config by writing `sudo raspi-config` there is option to enable glamor under `6. Advanced Options` menu